# Implementing AsyncQueryHandler with own SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm having some problems implementing an AsyncQueryHandler in my app.
I'm extending ExpandableListView and I have an internal SQLite Database. I would like to perform my queries using my own subclass of AsyncQueryHandler. 
The problem is simple, I believe... 
How to I supply the Uri object required in the methods startQuery/startInsert/startDelete/startUpdate from the AsyncQueryHandler class?
I simply don't know how to perform a query against my internal SQLite database through that method since it requires a Uri object which I have no clue where to get from.
So how do I create the Uri object needed for the method? 
I looked in the API Samples ExpandableListView2 but I couldn't quite grasp the code in it.
I don't know if it's relevant information but I'm not extending ContentProvider. 
Also, if you reckon that AsyncQueryHelper is not the best choice, should I go for AsyncTask?
If so, could you provide some sample code? 
I assume the query goes in doInBackgroud() and the setGroupCursor() and setChilderCursor() go into onPostExecute(), but I'm waiting for your replies.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to skip for now the asynchronous handling of ContentResolvers and use simple extension of AsyncTask instead to communicate to your database. Take a look at this examples:

[example1](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746) and [example2](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/android-database-example-database-usage-asynctask-database-export/)